# When build with latest Android NDK NativeActivity spams to log on touch events

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

For application build with latest NDK every touch event generates this error message in the application log:

> E/NativeActivity(20148): channel '425e6ad8
>   /android.app.NativeActivity (client)' ~ Failed to
>   receive dispatch signal. status=-11

Is it a bug or may be something has changed in native input processing?
Does anybody know how to fix it on application side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a change was made to the function:

```
process_input(struct android_app* app, struct android_poll_source* source)
```

in the android_native_app_glue.c file from the NDK.

It is a work-around for ANR hangs, but has a TTY spam as a side effect on many devices.
More info at http://ps3computing.blogspot.ca/2012/12/anr-application-not-responding.html